# Postgres - How to add new column uuid

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I need to add new column on my table would be uuid data type, here my code:

```
ALTER TABLE core.example add COLUMN newcolumn SET DATA TYPE UUID USING (uuid_generate_v4())
```

but show me this error:

```
ERROR:  type modifier is not allowed for type "uuid"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE core.example add COLUMN newsi UUID  (uuid_genera...
```

I dont want to alter a column, would be to create a new column on my table. Any idea how to make this?

Regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When adding a new column you don't use `SET DATA TYPE`. Your statement should look like:

```sql
ALTER TABLE core.example ADD COLUMN newcolumn UUID DEFAULT (uuid_generate_v4());
```

The DEFAULT clause will immediately fill the column with UUIDs.

Alternatively if you you just want to fill the column with initial data, you can drop the DEFAULT clause afterward:

```sql
ALTER TABLE core.example ALTER COLUMN newcolumn DROP DEFAULT;
```

Note that if you are using Postgres 13 and newer it is generally preferrable to use `gen_random_uuid()` since that method is built-in and does not rely on the `uuid-ossp` extension.